# Having a red line showSnackBar and error in when running the program

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, snackbar, scaffold

I am running my flutter app on Android Studio (mac) and I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPeCj.png)

How do I fix this? This is the original code:

```
Future showCopiedToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  final lang = Language.of(context);
  await FlutterClipboard.copy(text);
  final content = lang.copiedToClipboard(text);
  if (Scaffold.maybeOf(context) != null)
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: content,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    ));
```

I tried to search for it on Google but got no correct answer that would help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` instead of `Scaffold.of(context)`

Like so:

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: content,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    ));
```